# how can I run openvpn as daemon sending a config file?

Tags: debian, openvpn

I am using openvpn to connect with other server, the problem is that i run it like this

`openvpn configfile.ovpn` ... and it locks my shell, so, if I close it, the shell gets closed, I was looking for a way to initialize it as daemon, sending my configfile, but I could not find any, I saw the param `--configfile` but seems like I did not work the way I used it... any idea or way to do it??

I am using linux Debian 6

Thanks

**Edit:** My .ovpn file is like this:

```
dev tap
client
proto tcp-client
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client.pem
tls-remote "/O=WatchGuard_Technologies/OU=Fireware/CN=Fireware_SSLVPN_Server"
remote-cert-eku "TLS Web Server Authentication"
remote someIP 
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
keepalive 10 60
cipher BF-CBC
auth MD5
float 1
reneg-sec 3660
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
auth-user-pass
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use Debian's initscript for OpenVPN. Place your configuration in `/etc/openvpn/foo.conf` and then start it like this:

```
sudo service openvpn start foo
```

The service will be automatically started when the system boots, if you don't want this edit `/etc/default/openvpn` and change this line:

```
AUTOSTART="none"
```

**Edit:** You can get the client to read the username and password from a file specified with the `auth-user-pass` directive. This file should contain the username on the first line and password on the second.

```
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/password
```

Comment: thanks! im trying, but I cant find any docs about an example of how make the foo.conf or openvpn.conf, could you suggest me some links please?

Comment: @user156355 It's exactly the same configuration file that you're already using.

Comment: Thank you!! I moved all my files, configfile.ovpn and the crt (just in case) and I tried service openvpn start client (and client.ovpn) and I get an error, something like this "Starting virtual private network daemon:No such VPN: client.ovpn ... failed!" any idea?

Comment: @user156355 Check `/var/log/syslog`. You may need to adjust the paths to files like certificates.

Comment: my log file is empty, I updated my post with the code of my conf, could you please give it an eye?

Comment: @user156355 Actually, I see your problem. You must name your config `somename.conf` and just call it `somename` when starting it (as in my example).

Comment: thank you @mgorven , I tried only sudo service openvpn start without my .conf file, and when it starts asks me for user/password and then works, but... there is any way to include it? I found this function --auth-user-pass ... is it correct?

Comment: @user156355 See my edit.